# Is dynamic evaluation of XPath variable string possible using .NET 2.0 XSLT implementation?

Tags: .net, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to evaluate an [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) varable I'm building dynamically based on the position of the node.

I can create the XPath string in a variable but when I select the value of this just get the string and not the node set I need.

I use the following to create the XPath query.

```
<xsl:variable name="xpathstring" 
              select="normalize-space(concat(&quot;//anAttribute[@key='pos&quot;,position(),&quot;']&quot;))"/>
```

And try to output the value with the following.

```
<xsl:value-of select="$xpathstring"/>
```

If I execute the XPath query in my debugger I get the nodeset but in my XML output only get the XPath string which looks like this `//anAttribute[@key='pos1']`.

I had a look at `exslt dyn:evaluate` which seems to enable this but this seems to be only supported by certain processors and doesn't provide a standalone implementation or at least as far as I could see (currently using the standard .NET 2.0 [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) which is only XSLT 1.0 as far as I recall.)

Is there any way to handle this without changing processor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you not use a param instead of the concatenation:

```
<xsl:param name="pos">
    <xsl:text>pos</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
</xsl:param>
<xsl:value-of select="//anAttribute[@key=$pos]"/>
```

Comment: Thanks that works fine. I was banging my head against a wall trying to get it to work from the xpath string directly but this works fine.